# How are PCM signals put onto a wire?

Tags: signal, ethernet, signal-processing, pulse

I just want to get a sense of how **digital data** is physically transmitted over cables using protocols like USB or Ethernet.

I've read that they use PAM signaling (USB4 uses PAM-3, Gigabit Ethernet uses PAM-5), but I am unable to grasp how the real physical signals look on the wire.  Specifically:

do they look like sinusoidal waves (analog?) that are being modulated with some set discrete symbols and get sampled at the right rate on the other end of the wire? [image: like this]

or does each end have some sort of DAC that can put a specific voltage onto the wires and then updates the voltage to the next desired voltage in time with a clock? [image: like this]

Comment: PCM signals are not directly put on any of those buses, rather packets of data representing many PCM samples are transmitted in bursts of data.  Since those buses are thousands of times faster than typical audio interfaces, the burst will be very short followed by a long idle period until the next packets are ready to be sent.  Each interface will be different though, so there isn't a general answer beyond "voltages change on the wire to indicate ones and zeros".  Maybe there is one specific interface you want to ask about?  I think USB2 is most common for audio.

Comment: What about 10GBASE-T Ethernet? and I believe I made a mistake including the signal-processing tag, I don't actually mean specifically audio data, but am curious about how any digital data would look on the wire.

Comment: You should edit your question to reflect what you really wanted to ask. Regarding 10gbase-t, see: https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/64972/how-can-10gbps-travel-over-a-500mhz-ethernet-cable

Comment: @user1850479 I would like to know the high-level concept of how the hardware works that writes/reads the signals on the wire.  An individual transistor sets a line within a computer to hi/low.  For something like 10gbase-t that uses PAM-16, are 4 different transistors used to create the 2^4 different voltage amplitudes?

Comment: I'm not sure if I'm asking about something that is in fact obvious, or if I have an insufficient understanding of how signals are passed along wires to know what to ask in the first place.

Comment: I’d expect they’d use some form of DAC - this could be implemented many ways but I’d expect it would take a few transistors. The driver needs to be fast and needs to be able to source sufficient current. The signal might start out with clean edges but once it gets to a length of wire real world physics takes over and the edges are no longer sharp. You could research “PAM4 eye diagram” to see what it really looks like.